# Hungarian Algorithm Selecting 0s

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have a question very similar to the one found here:

[Hungarian algorithm - assign systematically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527299/hungarian-algorithm-assign-systematically)

He proposed a solution which may or may not work... but it doesn't exactly seem logically sound.

Is there a surefire dynamic algorithm to use to determine which set of 0's will be a viable solution? (meaning only one 0 per row and per column)

See step 9 on: http://www.wikihow.com/Use-the-Hungarian-Algorithm

How would one implement an algorithm to perform that task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you can look at the n*n matrix as representing a bipartite graph. Rows denote vertices in the left part of the graph, columns, denote vertices in the right part. A zero in row i, col j means that there is an edge between vertex i on the left side and vetex j on the right side.

You want to find a full bipartite matching, that is a set of n edges without common vertices. For this, you can use your favorite matching algorithm, for example Hopcroft-Karp.

Once you have found the matching, select the zeros that correspond to edges in your matching. The matching property guarantees that there is not more than one selected zero in each row/column.

Comment: This is the only way that worked for me – the greedy algorithms seem to work until you run them against thousands of random matrices and find some example that doesn't work.